# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una validación y retornar el valor de una función en Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy haciendo un pequeño programa en Kotlin, pero me surgieron algunas dudas ya que aun no soy tan bueno aplicando el paradigma orientado a objetos.

```
class Cuenta constructor(var clabe: String,var titular: String, var saldo: Double ) {

fun depositar () {

    print("Monto: ")
    var monto: Double = readLine()!!.toDouble()
    var saldofinal: Double = monto + saldo
    println("-------------RECIBO---------------")
    println(" ")
    println("Clabe: $clabe - Titular: $titular")
    println(" ")
    println("Acción: Deposito de Dinero")
    println("Monto: $$monto")
    println("Saldo anterior: $$saldo")
    println("Nuevo saldo: $$saldofinal")
}
```

```
fun main (args:Array<String>) {

    var cliente1 = Cuenta("01-8547-9","Alberto Palma", 5000.00)

    println("Menú")
    println("1 - Depositar")
    println("2 - Retirar")

    print("Ingrese la acción a realizar: ")
    var accion: Int = readLine()!!.toInt()

    when (accion) {

        1 -> cliente1.depositar()
        2 -> cliente1.retirar()
        else -> println("Fin del programa")
    }
}
```

1. ¿Cómo podría validar la variable `monto` para que solo se acepten valores de tipo numérico?
2. Después de que se termine de ejecutar el método `depositar ()` ¿Cómo puedo lograr que el ciclo se inicie de nuevo?

Answer (score 0):

respondiendoa tu pregunta

1. Podridas utilizar un regex y poder validar que solo sea de tipo numérico lo que se ingrese `[A-Z0-9<\n]+".toRegex().matches(text)`
2. Para el caso de que vuelvas a iniciar el ciclo, usa un `while` esto te permitirá repetir las veces que necesitas el fragmento de código que tienes.

Comment: En el caso del ciclo ¿tendría que hacerse desde la función main y no desde los métodos de la clase cierto?

Comment: Si tal cual mi estimado.